# Extreme lag when switching between views that has MapView

Tags: mapbox

I have 4 tab pages in my app. On page 3, thats where the MapView is, so when just loading from page 1 to page 2, it will preload page 3.

It causes tremendous lag. I tried just returning a blank fragment on PageAdapter only for that page and it doesn't seem to exhibit this behavior. This is extremely annoying and a lot of people has been complaining about it so far.

One of the things I did is simply add the MapView dynamically, it did solve the problem but MapView refuses to call the onMapReady for some reason.

Any ideas how can I at  least delay the loading of MapBox until the page has been fully transitioned?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you found any solution ? I am having same lagging issue. I have bottom bar with 5 fragments and one of the fragments has MapVIew, it lags a lot when user switches tabs rapidly which includes MapView fragment.